# Vim Statusline: Expression does not accept static function

Tags: vim

Of the two ways an expression - such as a function call - can be used instead of a literal value when setting `statusline`, neither seem to allow a static function.

1. `set statusline=%{s:MyFunc()}`
2. `set statusline=%!s:MyFunc()`

Both produce the following error pair.

- `E120: Using <SID> not in a script context: <SID>:MyFunc`
- `E15: Invalid expression: <SID>:MyFunc()`

I have `s:MyFunc()` defined in the same file where I'm trying to set `statusline`.

When I make the function global (`s:MyFunc` replaced by `MyFunc` everywhere in the file), there are no errors, and `statusline` is set properly. Hence this question.

Note that replacing `s:` with `<SID>:` did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don Cruickshank's explanation is correct. Here are some possible solutions that are better than defining a global function (though that would work, too, especially if you prefix the name with the script's name to make it unique):

1. Define and use an *autoload function* to localize the function; this can also be done in a `plugin/myscript.vim`, too, not necessarily in `autoload/myscript.vim`. E.g. `function myscript#MyStatuslineFunc()`
2. To use a script-local function, you need to make the translation of `s:` into the actual `<SNR>NNN_FuncName` (what mappings do automatically when you use `<SID>`) yourself:

```
function! s:function(name)
    return substitute(a:name, '^s:', matchstr(expand('<sfile>'), '<SNR>\d\+_\zefunction$'),'')
endfunction
let &statusline = '%!' . s:function('s:MyFunc()')
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried `execute 'set statusline=' . s:MyFunc()` and it worked! Seems to be the simplest solution of them all. :)

Comment: That's fine if you don't need `s:MyFunc()` evaluated all the time, just once for definition. It's a huge difference in semantics!

Comment: You're right! In my case, `s:MyFunc()` returns the same string always, so it should be fine. I could not understand what you meant by "evaluated all the time" though. For example, isn't `set statusline=%!MyFunc()` evaluated just once as well?

Comment: Okay, I added a print in `MyFunc()` and found out the difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`statusline` is not evaluated within the context of a script so trying to use a function from the local script with `s:` will always fail.

`s:` means that the given symbol is local to the script, not static, and so you will need to use another way of identifying the function.  See `:help E738` for a list of the possible symbol modifiers.

This, as you have stated in the question, will indeed work:

```
function MyFunc()
  return "Hello World"
endfunction

set statusline=%!MyFunc()
```